# Show that for all integers $a,b$ and every $n>0$, $(a+b)^n ≡ a^n + b^n \pmod 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that, for all integers $a,b$ and every $n>0$, $(a+b)^n ≡ a^n + b^n \pmod 2$.

I know that $$(a+b)^n = a^n + \dbinom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \cdots + \dbinom{n}{n-1}ab^{n-1} + b^n.$$ I know I need to show that $$2\mid\dbinom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \cdots + \dbinom{n}{n-1}ab^{n-1}.$$

Case 1: $2\mid n$, then we are done.

Case 2: $2\nmid n$. I need some help proving this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes remarkably simple if you first prove the following lemma:

> For all integers $a$ and $n > 0$, $\ a^n \equiv a \pmod 2$.

To prove this, consider the two cases: either $a$ is odd, or it is even...

Comment: To prove your lemma, I have considered the following:
case 1: a is even. a^n≡a(mod2) since 2|a(a^(n-1)-1) since 2|all even numbers a. 
case 2: a is odd. Need to show that 2|(a^(n-1)-1), or in other words, show that a^(n-1)≡1 (mod 2). Since in Z/2Z every number is unit, then it is true that a^(n-1)≡1 (mod 2) for all odd numbers a. So for all integers a and n>0,  a^n≡a(mod2). Does this seem like a valid proof for your lemma?

Comment: *every odd number is unit in Z/2Z

Comment: It looks OK, at least at a glance, but maybe a bit overcomplicated. You could just build a multiplication table for $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, or, if you like shooting flies with cannons, just appeal to Euclid's lemma to show that the product of odd numbers is odd.

Comment: Or factor $X^n-X=X(X-1)P$ with $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}X^i$, which when reduced modulo $2$ has roots that cover all of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind the binomial expansion or induction.

There are 3 cases: both a and b are even, both are odd, or one is odd and the other is even...

Comment: Except that there is also $n$ to deal with. For that you need the (easy) lemma in the answer by Ilmari Karonen. Indeed after replacing the exponents by $1$ there is no more need for case distinctions on $a,b$.